# Zoom H2 Levels Peculiarity

Tags: zoom, h2, levels

I've noticed a peculiarity of the H2 in that the levels it displays on the recorder itself does not match up exactly with the levels of Pro Tools - i.e. I'll think I'm clipping on the H2 by looking at the levels alone but when I dump it into Pro Tools the audio has at least 2 or 3 more dB of headroom.

Has anyone else noticed this? Is there an update or option I haven't found out about yet from the manual to switch metering methods?

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this as well. Not sure why it is. One of these days I'll actually put tone into the thing and see what the jam is.

Comment: Yes! I'm not crazy after all!